# Where does the module id come from in Durandal?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, durandal

I'm working on a legacy app in durandal. I noticed when I define a module:

`define({
  message: 'hello world'
});`

Then the output from grunt looks like:

`define('filePath\fileName',{
  message: 'hello world'
});`

Where does `filePath\fileName` come from?  I tried building a module in plain RequireJS and I had to supply this id myself.  I read that Durandal uses a pattern called AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition pattern).  Is the `filePath\fileName` using `fileName.js` convention a part of the AMD pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD optimizers add these ids when they optimize your modules.

As long as you have one module per file, an AMD loader is able to infer the module id from the path of the file and from the configuration of the module loader. So it is okay when you have one module per file to omit the module id from the `define` call, and let the AMD loader infer the module id. This is called an "anonymous `define`, by the way.

One of the jobs of the optimizer is to combine multiple modules in a single file. When the optimizer combines multiple modules in the same file, then there's no way to distinguish which `define` call belongs to which module, unless the optimizer also records this information. The way the AMD specification is designed, the way to record which `define` belongs to which module is to add the module id as the first argument of `define`.

Comment: Durndal mentions this feature in the [docs](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module.html) under the title "Module ID's". I assume there is a custom "durandal optimizer" somewhere in the source code.

Comment: The page you cite says "Durandal's module support is provided by RequireJS." So taking that at face value, this means that default optimizer that Durandal uses is [`r.js`](https://github.com/requirejs/r.js), since `r.js` is RequireJS's optimizer. If you are using `grunt-durandal` to optimize, it is just using `r.js` behind the scenes.